# Typescript Cannot dynamically import whatwg-fetch

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, import

Typescript has built in defs for `whatwg-fetch` now (I'm using v2.7), however it ignores them with dynamic imports:

```
import(/* webpackChunkName: "whatwg-fetch" */ 'whatwg-fetch')
```

> TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'whatwg-fetch'.
>   'C:/../node_modules/whatwg-fetch/fetch.js' implicitly has an 'any'
>   type.
>   Try `npm install @types/whatwg-fetch` if it exists or add a new
>   declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'whatwg-fetch';`

However if I install that the `@types/whatwg-fetch` type module as it suggests it has dozens of errors about duplicate definitions due to already having it built in...

How can I circumvent this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this by created a d.ts file - `whatwg-fetch.d.ts` with this inside:

```
declare module "whatwg-fetch";
```